# Safari genera problemas con type=date

Tags: reactjs, date, safari

Tengo problemas con el input="date de safari, no lo visualiza, más abajo dejaré una foto. Me podrían ayudar a encontrar por qué esto pasa, no tiene problemas el código con ningún otro navegador. Lo probe en Chrome, Opera y Firefox, solo en el Safari del mac presenta problemas.

event

```
                                    <input id="Date" type="date"
                                        name="Date" onChange={this.eventos}
                                        value={this.state.Date} />
                                    <label for="Date" > Fecha de nacimiento del paciente </label>

                                </div>
```

[image: Así se ve en Safari]

[image: Así se ven en Opera]

Estoy ocupando React, Node y MongoDB no sé si les sirva de algo esos datos.

Comment: En móvil o escritorio?

Comment: en escritorio, en móvil no tiene problemas, lo puse en descripción :(

Answer (score 0):

Pues si tiene problemas, en safari no esta soportado

https://caniuse.com/#feat=input-datetime

por eso la mayoría de los desarrollos web ocupan librerías para sus datetime pickers

si usas react podrías usar

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-datetime-picker